# How different applets are distinguished by web-browsers?

Tags: java, applet, jnlp, java-web-start, deployjava

If the user visits the website and install the applet, does a visit to another website, which contains the same applet, would use the previously installed applet?. Or, does it install the applet as a different one?

If they are treated as the same applet, is there an way to make applets treated as different ones by web-browsers? Perhaps, by modifying jnlp information while keeping all other elements, such as libraries, the same?

How does web-browser/java distinguishes the applets(jnlp) installed in websites? I can think of website URL or applet-desc in jnlp xml files.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested myself to grasp that jnlp applet is categorized by the URL even though they are essentially the same consisting of the identical libraries, jnlp file and etc.